# Very slow performance for inner join with restrictive where clause (very small subset of rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, inner-join, query-planner

I have two large tables that I am joining using an intermediate mapping table (details of structure below).

I am trying to join all three on `t1.date = t2.date` and `t1.id_a = int.id_a` and `int.id_b = t2.id_b`

I also have a where clause that restricts the data to a very specific range of the date column (result set is *~25k rows*).

Running either the join of table 1 and the int table (with where clause) or the join of table 2 with the int table (with where clause) takes literally 2 seconds each. It should then be trivial to join these two results sets that are around 37k rows for table 1 and 200k rows for table 2.

Instead it consistently takes 8 minutes for this query:

```
select t1.date, t1.id_b, t1.other_cols, t2.other_cols
from t1 
inner join t_int on t1.id_a = t_int.id_a
inner join t_2 on t2.date = t1.date and t2.id_b = t_int.id_b
where t1.date between '2018-10-21' and '2018-12-10'
```

In the estimated (and actual) execution plan, SQL Server says it will do:

> 1. clustered index seek on t1, seeking my date range (cost 33%)
> 2. compute scalar t.id_a (cost 0%)
> 3. clustered index seek on t2, seeking my date range (cost 33%)
> 4. nested loop to join [2] and [3] (cost 0%)
> 5. non clustered index seek on t_int, seeking t_int.id_a = t1.id_a and t_int.id_b = t2.id_b (cost 33%)
> 6. nested loop to join [4] and [5] (cost 0%)
> 7. compute scalar t.date, t_int.id_b (cost 0%)

```
Table 1:
date,
id_a,
other columns
```

(3.2m rows, date and id_a are primary key w clustered index)

```
Table 2:
date,
id_b,
other columns
```

(18.5m rows, date and id_b are primary key w clustered index)

Mapping table:

```
id_a,
id_b,
other columns
```

(35k rows, id_b is primary key w clustered index, additional non_clustered index on [`id_a, id_b, other_col`])

There are no other indexes and no constraints at all (apart from the mentioned primary key constraints).

I have already rebuilt the index on t2

Can anyone help with what I need to do?

Comment: [mcve] please. Besides the usual reasons, constraints & indexes are important here.

Comment: There are no indexes that aren't already mentioned, and no constraints at all

Comment: Try rebuild the indexes. it might help you.

Comment: But your post doesn't say that so we don't know. Plus the details of the indexes are not clear There are constraints--PK at least. Also if you could declare FKs then the DBMS could optimize with them. Besides there should be a [mcve] for the usual reasons. Like now I have had to write two comments. PS Please clarify via post edits not comments.

Comment: Point taken, I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already rebuilt the index on t2 because it was fragmented. But I hadn't rebuilt the index on t1 or t_int since they looked fine.

Thanks to Mohammad Mohabbati's suggestion in the comments, I rebuilt them all and the query now runs in less than 1 second.

So the answer here, which may be useful to others with similar problems, is "rebuild all the indexes, even if they look fine"

Comment: Mark this as answer. so , it is helpful for others.

Comment: Not able to do this for 2 days, I'll make a note to do that later this week